# Objective-C: no known class method for selector initWithRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to use `NSURLConnection` to "talk" to a server but when trying to use `initWitRequest` I get this error:

```
no known class method for selector 'initWithRequest:delegate:'
```

Is this not a proper usage of the method?

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

My Deployment Target is iOS 4.3.  Under Base SDK it has listed `Latest iOS (iOS 5.0)`.  Could this be an issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're attempting to send `-initWithRequest:delegate:` to the `NSURLConnection` `class` instead of an instance of that class.

By convention, any `-init` method should be preceded by a message to `alloc` on the class. In your example, `conn` would be created like so:

`NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];`

Comment: derrr.  Thank you very much.  No idea how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

`initWithRequest:delegate:` is an instance method, not a class method. You need to use `connectionWithRequest:delegate:`, which is a class method:

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```